# Getting error Client sent AUTH, but no password is set while initializing Redis object

Tags: python, flask, redis

I am fairly new to redis and using configuring redis with flask app.

i have edited redis.conf file and uncommented requirepass

`requirepass foobared`

and I am able to get into redid-cli using this password.

like this `./redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a foobared`

but when I try to initialise an object of Redis class by passing in the password,

```
>>> import os
>>> import redis
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> from redis import Redis
>>> app = Flask('weatherApp')
>>> app.config["REDIS_HOST"] = os.getenv("REDIS_HOST")
>>> app.config["REDIS_PORT"] = os.getenv("REDIS_PORT")
>>> app.config["REDIS_PWD"] = os.getenv("REDIS_PWD")
>>> app
<Flask 'weatherApp'>
>>> app.config
>>> redis = Redis(app.config["REDIS_HOST"], port=app.config["REDIS_PORT"],
...     db=0, password=app.config["REDIS_PWD"])
>>> redis.client_list()
```

I keep getting the error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/weatherApp/src/views.py", line 192, in dispatch_request
    print redis.client_list()
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 703, in client_list
    return self.execute_command('CLIENT LIST')
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 667, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 493, in connect
    self.on_connect()
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 561, in on_connect
    if nativestr(self.read_response()) != 'OK':
  File "/Users/ciasto-piekarz/Development/web/python/flask/flsk-dimnd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 629, in read_response
    raise response
ResponseError: Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Um... try to delete `app.config["REDIS_PWD"] = os.getenv("REDIS_PWD")`? It says you shouldn't send password.

Comment: If you can login without password, that means there is a no-password user in your redis. You need to check.

Comment: I have configured same environment variables in heroku configurations which is why I am setting the same in local so when I push to heroku it should still work

Comment: Can you maybe run a "printenv" to list all variables and double check your REDIS_PWD is there? or just print os.getenv("REDIS_PWD")

Comment: just did exactly this but it doesnt work.